# How can I add series of points to q3dsurface?

Tags: c++, qt5, data-visualization

I am looking for a way to create some single points on q3dsurface.
I have a Qt5 app that seeks a minimum of a nonlinear functions and visualising it in a 3dgraph.
The function is visualised as a Q3dSurface and I don't know how to create points on the surface which are the next points found in iterative seeking of minimum.

I tried to use QCustom3DItem but I need sth like selected point in 3dsurface.
The best would be simple:

```cpp
void Graph::drawSolution(const SSolution& solution)
{
    for (const auto& item : solution)
    {
        _surface->addPoint(QVector3D(item.first.x(1),item.first.x(2),item.second));
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to create a series of points on Q3dSurface?
Maybe somebody knows how to create Q3dScatter and Q3dSurface on the same graph?

Comment: You could add the points as `QCustom3DItem`s, however you would need to create a wavefront mesh file that resembles a sphere or have points rendered as a box (`QCustom3DVolume`).

Comment: hmm but if I use it, I will have to create manually the mesh file and include it to my project as a resource, am i wrong?

Comment: I would like to avoid using external files, instead I want to use some Qt component

Comment: I agree, it's not an elegant solution. Maybe the best you can do though.

Comment: @ypnos do you mind telling me how to create a wavefront mesh file?